# Returning list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, c#-4.0

I am retrieving multiple records from database and storing it in list. I have created properties class and then i assign data being retrieved to variables in properties and then trying to return all collection of values to client who made function call but it doesn't work. Why ? please make it correct.

Code:

```
 public Properties FetchCoordinates(String FetchParam) 
    {
        String[] parts = FetchParam.Split(',');
        sqlCom.CommandText = "FetchCoordinates";
        sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[0].ToString();
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[1].ToString());
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeTo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[2].ToString());
        SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
        sqlCom.Parameters["@result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        List<Properties> props = new List<Properties>();
        Properties p;

        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader())
{
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                p = new Properties()
                {
                    Longitude = reader["Longitude"].ToString(),
                    Latitude  = reader["Latitude"].ToString()
                };
                props.Add(p);
                return p;
            }

}



        }



        catch (Exception ex)
        {



        }

        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

Properties.cs

```
public class Properties
{
    public Properties()
    {
    }

    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Your function is trying to return a single `Properties` object.  You should return `List<Properties>`

Answer (score 4):

Change the method signature;

```
public List<Properties> FetchCoordinates(String FetchParam)
```

and rather than returning `p` which is only a single instance, return the List props;

```
 while (reader.Read())
            {
                p = new Properties()
                {
                    Longitude = reader["Longitude"].ToString(),
                    Latitude  = reader["Latitude"].ToString()
                };
                props.Add(p);

            }

 return props;
```

Comment: ok what if exception is generated then some string message should be passed to client but how ? it only returns list

Comment: and how many times should i return Props, i returned one after while loop and one after finally block because functions was throwing error that not code path return.